# I would like to horizontally align a HTML element to a specific place in the document

Tags: javascript, html, typesetting

How can I horizontally align one HTML element to one elsewhere in the document? I came up with this solution aligning “aligned text” with “| text after alignment”, but I think that it is not good because it requires a lot of extra tags, and it seems that there should be a more standard way. I would like to use it for aligning code listing, so I want little markup overhead because it adds up with a lot of aligned elements.

This is an adaptation of my previous solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71843580/7281855), which is roughly how I would use it.

```js
function main() {
  let tabs = document.querySelectorAll("[anchor]");
  for (let tab of tabs) {
    let x = tab.offsetLeft;
    let tabstop = document.getElementById(tab.getAttribute("anchor"));
    let tabstopX = tabstop.offsetLeft;
    let offset = tabstopX - x;
    tab.style.left = `${offset}px`;
    tab.style.position = "relative";
  }
}

window.onload = main
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>text before alignment <align-anchor id=1></align-anchor>| text after alignment</p>
    <p>some other text in the way</p>
    <p anchor=1>aligned text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

[ID attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) should not begin with a number.

> Technically, the value for an id attribute may contain any character,
> except whitespace characters. However, to avoid inadvertent errors,
> only ASCII letters, digits, '_', and '-' should be used, and the value
> for an id attribute should start with a letter.

Answer (score 1):

> I think that it is not good

Disagree. I think it is good.

It has a well-focused goal, with a portable concise robust implementation.

It's too bad we can't get away with self-closing `<align-anchor id=1 />`

> requires a lot of extra tags

Yeah. Sorry, I don't see a good way out of that.
It's not like we're doing N-column table layout,
so it seems like we're just going to need a bunch of tags to accomplish that.

Hmmm, let's see.
What if we relaxed the "must display in proportional font!" requirement?
With fixed-width (`<pre>`) font, the text itself could give the
specs on what must align with what.
Scan the text to learn of all the tab stops,
then in a second scan insert the various `<align-anchor>` and `anchor` markup.
But I fear it would be less robust than the current implementation,
more fragile w.r.t. different input text patterns.

Almost equivalently, you might insert characters at start-of-line,
so the first two or three characters before SPACE are `>12`,
something like that, indicating we should go to tab stop 12.
Regex would be `^>\d{1,2}\s`.
That would play fine with the existing align anchors.
Use some crazy Unicode arrow (sentinel) if you feel that `">"`
is too common a character which source text might want displayed
in first column.

> How can it be done so that the code is aligned first and then displayed?

Initially set `visibility: hidden;` and let it render.
Then configure tab stops.
Then make the rendered text visible.
Voila, no distracting "blink"!

## span

The align-anchor spelling is nice enough.
But it feels kind of like a span.
And besides, it's possible that some of the displayed text
will already be marked up with `<span ...>` anyway.
So maybe make the anchor a `span` attribute? Just a thought.

## documentation

The JS code is clear.
All I would ask for is a sentence or two of "theory of operation",
explaining how text alignment is achieved, or at least an URL reference
to some ReadMe document.

As usual, unit tests wouldn't hurt.
Plus a system test, which renders onscreen and
advises a human tester to verify that certain points
really do line up on the browser version currently being used.

---

This codebase achieves its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: Thanks for the review. Alignment with a fixed-width font in `<pre>` is not viable because the point of that is to not rely on a text grid. I got the idea when I tried programming in a proportional font and tried to solve alignment there. The alignment in editors could be solved by [elastic tabstops](https://nickgravgaard.com/elastic-tabstops/), but they are supported almost nowhere. So I try to solve it at least in typesetting, where I can have other ways of alignment and real time is not a requirement.

Comment: I meant that instead of sending "text <align-anchor id=x1>before\n<p anchor=x1>aligned", we could send the simpler "text before\nSPC SPC SPC SPC SPCaligned". (That's five 0x20 space characters before the "a".) So monospaced we see that "aligned" lines up with "before". Now use that to transform the text to the version with <align-anchor ... and <p anchor ..., and render in a proportional font. // I confess that there _can_ be ambiguities, so "first one wins!". First line that sets a TAB stop at X will control how all subsequent lines within the <div> will layout, if they start with X spaces.